# Problem in Differential Equation (How to proceed?)

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

$$y\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{1-y^2}$$, y=0 when x=0

$$\frac{\frac{dy}{dx}y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}=1$$

$$\int\frac{\frac{dy}{dx}y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}dx=\int 1dx$$

$$-\sqrt{1-y^2}=x+c_1$$

$$1-y^2=(x+c_1)^2$$

$$y^2=1-(x+c_1)^2$$

$$y=\pm \sqrt{1-(x+c_1)^2}$$

When x=0, y=0

$$0=\pm \sqrt{1-c^2_1}$$

Comment: Looks like you've done the hard part.  The rest is just algebra.  Start by squaring both sides.

Comment: $-(1-y^2)=(x+c_1)^2$ is it correct ?

Comment: Sign error, should be $1-y^2=\dots$.

Comment: I've found $y=\pm \sqrt{-x^2-2x}$, but the given answer is $y=\pm \sqrt{-x^2\mp -2x}$. Why? @Mike

Comment: if  $y = 0$ at $x = 0$ and you must have $y\frac{dy}{dx} = \sqrt{1 - y^2}$ implies $\frac{dy}{dx}$  is undefined at $x = 0.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Square both sides:

$$1-y^2=(x+c_1)^2$$

rearrange for $y^2$:

$$y^2=1-(x+c_1)^2$$

take $\pm$ square root:

$$y=\pm\sqrt{1-(x+c_1)^2}$$

Comment: Where is the negative sign for the 1-y^2?

Comment: @Mathxx Whether you want to treat $-\sqrt u$ as $-1$ times $\sqrt u$ or simply the negative square root of $u$, the minus sign will go away when you square it.

Comment: The negative sign is gone because he is squaring both sides.

Comment: When I substitute x=0,y=0, I'm stuck . Can you show me ? Thanks @Mike

Comment: @Mathxx Again, it looks straightforward.  Exactly where are you getting stuck?

Comment: @Mike I've found $y=\pm \sqrt{-x^2-2x}$, but the given answer is $y=\pm \sqrt{-x^2\mp -2x}$. Why?

Comment: @Mathxx You should have gotten from plugging into danima's solution $c_1^2=1$.  It looks like you missed $c_1=-1$

Comment: I've edited the post. Can you help me to proceed? @Mike

Comment: @mathxx Similar to before, square both sides, then add $c_1^2$ to both sides or simply factor as $(1-c_1)(1+c_1)$.

Comment: @Mike. Thanks. I've found my mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^y \frac{y\, dy}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} = \int_0^x dx \to \sqrt{1-y^2} - 1=x$$ solving it gives you $$y = \pm \sqrt{2x-x^2}$$ is the circle or radius $1$ centered at $(1,0).$

$\bf note:$ use the definite integral whenever possible.